# Which is faster between static and dynamic getSObjects?

Tags: apex, relationships, performance, dynamic-apex

What is the difference in execution between . (dot) notation and getSObjects method? Omitting of course that I can parametrize with string getSObjects method.

**for example:**

```
Account.AccountContactRoles
```

**and**

```
Account.getSObjects('AccountContactRoles');
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<s>Functionally, there is no difference. These two options return the same data.</s> These functions are mostly the same.

From a performance perspective, the static approach is approximately 2.5x faster. I ran 25 trials each of 1,000 calls, and the static approach averaged 20.48 ms (20.48 µs per call), whereas the dynamic approach averaged 51.40 ms (51.40 µs per call).

```
Approach    Min CPU/iteration (µs)    Max CPU/iteration (µs)    Avg CPU/iteration (µs)
Static                       15.00                     32.00                     20.48
Dynamic                      40.00                     66.00                     51.40
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed test and answer! I did some tests myself but I was not sure. I got a similiar result.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Not sure I have a better use case but the `getSObjects` is useful when you need to keep dependencies out of a managed package. otherwise I am hard pressed to find a reason to use it in this context vs the static approach. Any other use cases for using `getSObjects`

Comment: @Eric It seems like a useful method but I can't say I've found occasion to use it either.

Answer (score 6):

I was bothered by null pointer exception when i was experimenting with my code. I changed static access method to getSObjects method and  found a strange thing which could be important, when we use getSObjects method and related list is empty then returns null, opposite to static method which always returns a empty list. It happend to me when I was trying to access related list of object inside for loop

```
for(Account acc : accounts){
acc.getSObjects('AccountContactRoles'); // returns null
acc.AccountContactRoles;                // returns empty list
}
```

Comment: You are correct. `getSObjects` returns null if the subquery is empty. an important point to remember

Answer (score 5):

I tried to retest the performance of the 3 approaches (added [`getSObjects(SObjectField)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) approach).

Org Params:

```
ApiVersion: 51.0
InstanceName: CS100
IsSandbox: true
OrganizationType: Developer Edition
```

Results for `50` trials each of `20.000` calls:

| Approach | MIN CPU (ms) | MAX CPU (ms) | AVG CPU (ms) | STD (σ) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `acc.Contacts` | 10.00 | 16.00 | 12.63 | 1.83 |
| `acc.getSObjects('Contacts')` | 16.00 | 24.00 | 16.93 | 2.19 |
| `acc.getSObjects(Contact.AccountId)` | 30.00 | 57.00 | 38.70 | 6.10 |

[image]

The static approach is still expectedly the fastest and approximately `1.35x` faster than dynamic. `SObject.getSObjects(SObjectType)` approach not only the slowest one, but also the most "unstable" having the greatest value of [`STD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

The result of benchmarking always depends on many factors, so in your case the results may differ. In this case, I was interested in comparing **relative** results.